# Using google DNS in netcfg

Tags: networking, dns

how can I set up my netcfg profiles to use the google DNS servers?
I've tried

```
IP = 'dhcp'
DNS = '8.8.8.8'
```

but that didn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put the custom DNS addresses into your DHCP server's configuration, so your clients get told to use them instead of the defaults.

If your DHCP server is a router and it doesn't give you the ability to change the DNS addresses, you can always run your own DHCP server. There are other reasons to do that besides custom DNS server IPs. For example, [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) will act as a LAN DNS cache, too, and integrates the DHCP and DNS so you get nice features like the ability to `ping` a DHCP client by name.

Comment: can you tell me how to properly configure this? I'm not a networking/internet wiz and frankly I know nothing about DNS. All I know is that I would like to be able to visit the websites which my government has censored.

Comment: If you're asking how you configure your router's DHCP server, that depends on your router type, and isn't on topic here. Try our sister site [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/). Include the make and model of the router. If you mean "how do you configure dnsmasq", that's covered by its documentation. There is a [setup guide](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html), a [FAQ](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/FAQ), and a [reference manual](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html).